# Is there a way to first test Facebook's Instant Articles on a mock page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-articles

Ok so I manage few WordPress news websites and I want to test out the Instant Articles.
Thing is when I go sign up, only Facebook pages that are those of the websites are available to be selected but not my new Page that I created just for testing.

Is there a way to make this work, I have no intention of straight up implementing it with real pages?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/get-started/test-and-debug

Comment: that's not what I'm looking for as I cant enable Instant Articles on my Demo Page and don't have the "Instant Articles" option in Page Manager App. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Well then create a new page for testing, and connect your site to that one, too?

Comment: The problem is that you can't connect your site unless it has a 'readership'. Trust me, i've tried. If you are just making 3rd party integrations for articles, then not allowing dev/test sites really complicates things.